# Get access to the last object from foreign key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, orm

My models are here:

```py
class UserToPackageMeta(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="package_metas"
    )
    package = models.ForeignKey(
        "platforms.Package", on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name="user_metas"
    )


class Package(models.Model):
    platform = models.ForeignKey(
        Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="packages"
    )


class Platform(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to write a query to get users based on platfrom slug on *last* package they have because any user can have diffrante packages:

I tried this:

```
users = users.filter(package_metas__package__platform=platform)
```

But this won't consider only the last package for each user.

Comment: Define "last"... Your `UserToPackageMeta` model doesn't have a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a date timestamp to your model:

```
class Package(models.Model):
      platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      created_on = models.DateTimeField("Creation Date", blank=True, null=True)
```

And then order by date (use `-` in front for descending):

```
user_packages = users.filter(package_metas__package__platform=platform)
last_package = result.order_by("-package_metas__package__created_on")[0]
```